# laravel 5.3 first page not showing

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5.3

I have install apache2 and laravel 5.3 in my system.I have assign port 8081 to

```
/var/www/html/laravel
```

folder. Now i am trying to execute

`http://localhost:8081/`

so its showing me all folders of laravel instead of execute default page of laravel.So is that correct ?

Is there need to do some changes in configuration.php file for that ?

Comment: You need to point it to `/var/www/html/laravel/public`

Comment: Thanks for reply.Let me try

Comment: Okay,seems like its working. it showing me first page like "Be right back."

Comment: is that error page instead of welcome page ?

Comment: It could be a maintenance page or an error page. Check your logs (found in `storage/logs/`, and your configuration.

Comment: Okay,You are right its maintenance page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be about the '.htaccess' file. Please create a .htaccess file in public folder, then fill inside like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/'; //************** Make change in this line to default redirection in laravel 7 or in any version*****************strong text**

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Something wrent wrong with your formatting. You should fix it. And please add a small summary before the code instead of only using inline comments.